# Physics of shape of balloons tied together

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Okay so I saw 4 balloons tied together and they formed this tetrahedral shape and I couldn't help but notice that they look like atomic orbitals. Is there any actual physical concept behind this? I mean is it like energetically or kinetically favourable for the balloons to assume this shape?

[image: This picture illustrates my point]

Comment: Atomic orbitals don't ever assume a tetrahedral shape. Hybridized $sp^3$ orbitals in carbon-carbon bonds do, but that's only within a molecule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some physical concepts behind it, but it is closer related to geometry and available space than it is to atomic orbitals.  To me, these shapes resemble atomic packing more than they do atomic orbitals.

This situation is fairly easy to understand in classical physics anyways.  Since the balloons are all tied together, the parts tied want to all be as close as possible, because the connection is elastic.  The further apart the middle of the balloons are, the greater the force trying to pull them together; so the orientation will tend to go towards an equilibrium where the force is minimized in some stable configuration.

You could imagine an orientation where all 4 balloons are essentially in a 2-D plane, making a cross.  In that scenario, as an example, the tied together parts of the balloon are further apart than in this tetrahedron.  If you were to slightly perturb one of the balloons in the cross, it is possible that it would move itself into the tetrahedron orientation due to the elastic forces pulling the tied balloons together.

Essentially, due to the elastic forces, the balloons will naturally try to minimize the distance between their centre connection points.  This tetrahedron is an orientation where the balloons can pack together much tighter than if they are all aligned in a 2-D plane.  This orientation is probably the most stable for 4 balloons, so it is quite likely that they will take this shape quite often, as long as they don't get stuck in some other quasi-stable equilibrium.

A similar example can be visualized with the [close packing of spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres). It is a bit different in that case because unlike tied balloons, the spheres aren't all attracted at one central point; and it is an infinite lattice instead of just 4 isolated spheres; but it may help to visualize how the elastic connections could force the system into this equilibrium.